# Create custom dataset by labelimg

Tags: annotations, dataset, labelimg

I've done labels on my dataset. My dataset has 5 classes. namely riders, helmets, without helmets, license plates and rearview mirrors.

the problem is why every time I open labeling or there is an error image that cannot be accessed, the dataset that I have labeled has changed and does not match the category, it is like being swapped between classes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWgV1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I would like to recommend that simple remove the current labelimg and install it again using command

```
git clone https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg.git
```

And, after that make sure you have "in your fingertips" the meaning of the file:

[image]

...and also browse the file structure of labelimg and get familiar with settings-like files it, and I suppose this way you will find the solution for your problem!